# jquery date picker refresh on click disabled days

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker set up with disabled days for when all available hours are booked or for days off.  When an available date is selected a function runs to fill an array of available time slots.  If a disabled day is clicked, the available hours from the prior selected day remain in the view. I get the roll over pop up saying there are no available slots. But the array of dates from the prior selection is not cleared or refreshed because the function will not run on a disabled date.  How can I run my function when a disabled day is clicked to clear the hours?  Or how can I clear the hours from the screen when I click on a disabled part of the calendar?

Comment: Craig, can you put together a small mockup on [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), and also provide a snippet of code most closely relating to the functionality you currently have. This will help us assist you better.

Comment: This is essentially what I am seeing https://jsfiddle.net/sN63A/97/.  If you select an active date the date shows up in the text box.  That is good.  What I would like is if I select an disabled date, or click on a navigation button for the text box to clear.  But what happens is the previously selected date stays in the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting an event listener to clear the array when the user clicks on the datepicker:

```
$('#datepicker').on('click', function(){
    // clear array of available time slots
});
```

Comment: Ok, this is close: https://jsfiddle.net/cravaus/sN63A/98/.  So it woks in the jsfiddle but not in my script.  The structure is essentially the same but the click events are not being caught on my site.  I will update my question with more code.

Comment: Well, now it works.  I am not sure what I was doing wrong but now it works.  Thank you.